# Weird URL-behaviour with Maven Release-Plugin

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm facing a pretty strange problem. I want to use the Maven Release-plugin (2.0) to release a project. Additionally I'm using GIT on a Stash-Server. The relevant part of the pom looks like this:

```
 25 <scm>
 26         <connection>scm:git:https://host-url.com/path/to/repository.git</connection>
 27         <developerConnection>scm:git:https://host-url.com/path/to/repository.git</developerConnection>
 28         <url>https://host-url.com/path/to/repository.git</url>
 29 </scm>
```

Now the release-plugin produces the following error:

```
19-Nov-2013 17:03:33    [ERROR] error: Couldn't resolve host 'host-url.compath' while accessing http://host-url.com/path/to/repository.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
```

As you may notice, it only kills the part between the first two slashes. So I tried adding multiple extra-slashes, but it happens to always take the first non-empty string between to slashes and concatenate it to the url. I seriously have no idea what causes this behaviour and I've now spent several hours fiddling around with the URL. Any suggestions?

Edit:
Same error with release-plugin 2.3.2 and Maven 3.1.

```
20-Nov-2013 09:06:05    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project project-name: Unable to commit files
20-Nov-2013 09:06:05    [ERROR] Provider message:
20-Nov-2013 09:06:05    [ERROR] The git-push command failed.
20-Nov-2013 09:06:05    [ERROR] Command output:
20-Nov-2013 09:06:05    [ERROR] error: Couldn't resolve host 'host-url.compath' while accessing http://host-url.com///////////path/to/repository.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
```

Comment: Start by telling the version of the maven-release-plugin. Be sure it is locked. The default version has been 2.0 for a lot of Apache Maven releases, even though there have been several releases of this plugin. In case of GIT I would start with using version 2.3.2.

Comment: It's in fact 2.0. I'm going to try it with 2.3.2

Comment: I just switched to Maven 3.1 with release-plugin 2.3.2 and got the same error.

Comment: Next step: execute Maven with debug logging ( `mvn -X ....` ) and verify how git is executed. You might see where the URL got broken. Also verify your URL with http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html

Comment: I didn't find any useful information regarding the URL with `-X` and double-checked my URL for typos, while looking at http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html. It looks right in my eyes.

Comment: Weird. Somehow adding a username&password to the URL fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the error had something to do with wrong user permissions in stash. I fixed the permissions for the repository and it worked fine.